# Difference between const auto &it and auto &it

Tags: c++, auto

I just submitted an ans in an online judge(SPOJ) and got a different result. let me first show both code:

`#1`

```
map<pair<int,int>,int>m;
bool flag=0;
for(auto &it:m)//difference
    {
       if(it.second>=2)
       {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) printf("Scenario #%d: possible\n",cnt);
    else printf("Scenario #%d: impossible\n",cnt);
```

`#2`

```
map<pair<int,int>,int>m;
bool flag=0;
for(const auto &it:m)//difference
    {
       if(it.second>=2)
       {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) printf("Scenario #%d: possible\n",cnt);
    else printf("Scenario #%d: impossible\n",cnt);
```

`This is the part of code I changed.`

The result for the first one was TimelimitExceed, while for the second one it got AC.
As far as I know **const auto &it** creates const reference of the map and **auto &it** creates reference which isn't constant.
But here I didn't try to change the value of map or any sort of thing like that, just checked through conditions and printed the result. Then why I am getting different results in online judge. Is there something else I am missing about const auto &it?

`Edit ::`
As some of you wanted to see the full code, I have added it(this one got TLE) in the post
If anyone is interested in possible inputs, here is the **OJ link:** https://www.spoj.com/problems/RPLD/

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;    
    int cnt=0;
    while(t--)
    {
        cnt++;
        int N, R;
        cin>>N>>R;
        map<pair<int,int>,int>m;
        while(R--)
        {
            int I, C;
            cin>>I>>C;
            m[{I,C}]++;
        } 
        bool flag=0;
        for(auto &it:m)
        {
            if(it.second>=2)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!flag) printf("Scenario #%d: possible\n",cnt);
        else printf("Scenario #%d: impossible\n",cnt);
 
    }
}
```

Comment: To the extent there is a problem, it likely lies in the code not shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: It's possible that the compiler can optimize the code when you have a const reference, but those optimizations don't kick in when you have a non-const reference.

Comment: m is empty so the for loop will skip.

Comment: For me, it is just a coincidence. The online judge have some fixed timeouts, but the time to run the same program several times can vary quite a lot, depending notably on the load of the server and whether data is in cache or not.

Comment: While I am convinced that @cigien is basically right, I have a feeling that Igor is closer. I expect online judges to have their TLE borders where the difference is made by getting the right algorithm, not by getting the right tinkering-optimisation. I.e. if you get the algo right, the kind of opitimisation discussed by cigien should not matter. Again, cigiens input is NOT irrelevant for optmisation here, but it comes AFTER algo-optimisation and should be irrelevant for the special case of challenge judges.

Comment: @doug as I said, it was part of the code where I changed, so inputs were missing. But now, I have edited with full code, hope it helps